# .go to ban an ip using ufw

Tags: go, ufw

Okay, so here is the original code, which works fine.

```
if len(data) > 1 {
  var req StratumReq
  err = json.Unmarshal(data, &req)
  if err != nil {
    s.policy.ApplyMalformedPolicy(cs.ip)
    log.Printf("Malformed stratum request from %s: %v", cs.ip, err)
    return err
  }
}
```

However instead of just printing the error I want to use ufw in Ubuntu 16.04 to ban the ip.  However I'm not too familiar with this type of coding to get the correct syntax to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.  It's written in .go

Answer (score 0):

You can  execute the command by using  [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)

```
if err != nil {
    s.policy.ApplyMalformedPolicy(cs.ip)

    out, err := exec.Command(fmt.Sprintf("ufw deny from {%d} to any",cs.ip).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("Malformed stratum request from %s: %v", cs.ip, err)
    return err
}
```